# Can't open pip in Python version 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Using Python version 3.5 on Windows 10 64bit,
I'm unable to run the pip command. When I try running the application, the window will just open for a brief second and then closes.
I already tried adding the directory to the `PATH` environment variable and rebooting the system - didn't work.

Comment: You have not included enough information. What OS are you using? What is the error you receive when trying to run `pip`? Please edit the question and expand on those details.

Comment: pip or pip3? They are different

Comment: Have you tried `pip --version`? @NoamZar

Comment: i tried both, neither of them work

Comment: Pip is not a command line. You should start a command line and type pip inside it.

Comment: @NoamZar `pip --version`?

Comment: The python 3 installer offers to add the necessary PATH variables. You shouldn't need to mess with them

Answer (score 1):

> when i try running the application the window will just open for brief second and then closes

Sounds like you are trying to open the `pip.exe` file and expect an interactive interface of some kind.

Unfortunately, that's not how you use `pip`. Open up a `cmd`, type your pip commands there. The command prompt will print and error, and not close, if there is a problem.